# Can't compress my App for distribution

Tags: iphone, compression

Compression process for one of my Applications build gets stuck and never finishes the 
compression process (eternally stating "2.6 MB of 2.7 MB about 5 sec").

I couldn't find the solution by googling - even though I am not the first one to  have this 
issue.

Does any body know a fix to this issue?

Comment: What if you copy the files to another location and try from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of the trouble-

I dragged the same file twice into the project -

now I have deleted one of the aliases and it zipped with the usual right click + compress.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that before. What you could do is try another zip-tool. Maybe on another machine. Or delete some files from the problematic application directory, just to see which one is causing the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the idea- I succeeded zipping that file using a free zipping tool I found on the web.